# Image recognition OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing, machine-learning

My project is to analyze a dataset containing images of birds. After that, the program should recognize whether the input image is a bird or not.

**I plan to use OpenCV with C++. Could someone suggest me the modules required and the procedure in which this program should be made for recognizing if the input is a bird or not after reading the image dataset.  (I'm a beginner in OpenCV)**

Comment: It is not about OpenCV or C++ or programming in general. This is about a solution pipeline. You're approaching the problem upside down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of ways to go about solving this problem, however the solution I think would probably have the best chance of success would be to train your own haar cascade.

You will need *alot* of images containing birds and a *helluva lot* of images **without** birds in. If you already have access to this dataset you need to analyze, then you already got alot of images (some of which you can train with)

A haar cascade essentially searches the image for patterns it has been trained to recognize (such as a face, eyes, nose etc which comes with OpenCV)

[Here](http://nayakamitarup.blogspot.in/2011/07/how-to-make-your-own-haar-trained-xml.html) is a link to a tutorial/tools for making training your own cascade as painless as possible.

Follow the instructions and at the end you should have an XML file that will be your Cascade for birds.

[Here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html) is a tutorial on how to *use* your new cascade. I suggest you read up on how cascade classifiers work in general as it will help you understand what kind of images to train on, and what tweaking you can do to your images to ensure the best possible chance of detection.

Another option you could pursue would be to just use OpenCV for preprocessing and then send your image to a neural network for classification.

This could involve removing as much "background noise" information as possible from the image such as removing the colour bright green (unless you have bright green birds of course), smooth and scale down the image (take some weight off the network) and then plug the rest of the info to your network. I have no idea how successful this might be as I have never used a network for detection, only for face recognition, but it did a pretty damn good job at that, so give it a shot.

Good luck and I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In order to accomplish this task, you will have to train your very own cascade classifier which by no mean is an easy task for a beginner.

For more information on how this can be achieved please perform your own research as they are loads of examples online. I have listed a link below to get you started.

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html

Comment: won't work. there's too many different species / shapes. also, cascade-classifiers are not pose invariant. last but not least, your links are outdated, and refer to methods no more applicable with current opencv (the tools / fileformats have changed significantly)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback on this. Regarding the species of birds, I guess this depends on how many samples are been used and obviously realistic expectation. I was not aware of this method being no longer applicable, since it's still currently been used for face detection.